# Setting up XAMPP and Sendmail to enable WordPress emails on localhost

Tags: localhost, xampp

I am trying to enable email sending from my localhost installation of WordPress. I need to do so to test out some notification functionality as well as alerts and password resets.

I know that you must configure your php.ini and sendmail.ini, and that it is apparently quite easy, but I can't for the life of me get it to work. My php.ini file contains:

**PHP.ini**

```
[mail function]
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like Mercury
 SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
 smtp_port=587
 sendmail_from=gmail-account@gmail.com
 Sendmail.ini
```

**Sendmail.ini**

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=gmail-account@gmail.com
auth_password=gmail-password
force_sender=gmail-account@gmail.com
```

I'm wondering if I have set up something incorrectly as I'm not currently receiving any emails when I do a password reset.

I also have mercury installed and running. Is there something wrong in one of my files, or have I missed a step? Everything I'm reading says this should be simple, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't a wordpress specific problem - see what's on topic at [help/on-topic]. For this reason the question probably should be migrated to [sf]. Apart from that, I usually setup the `mail()` functionality with `postfix` under ubuntu, take a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47609/how-to-have-my-php-send-mail), [here](http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133499/xampp-osx-lion-get-mail-to-work).

Comment: @toscho made me realize, by letting me read the [server fault on-topic page](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic), that [sf] isn't the right place. Additionally he linked me to [Do questions on WAMP belong on Stack Overflow, Server Fault or Super User?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208052/do-questions-on-wamp-belong-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-or-super-user), which leads to the conclusion there's no definitive answer where to ask your kind of question, it depends on the problem, read the meta discussion for a insight.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was able to resolve the issue. I was directed here from SO.

Inside of my php.ini file I commented out the wrong line. I was enabling mail through send disk and not sendmail.

Comment: Good for you! It happens that [so] redirects questions/people here, because the word »wordpress« appears in their problem, but this is definitely not in scope of [wordpress.se].

Comment: That's what I figured. Sorry to place the question over here. I can mark the question as answered by 10pm tonight (due to my new account). Thanks again for your response. Have a great day ialocin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Inside of my php.ini file I commented out the wrong line. I was enabling mail through send disk and not sendmail.